# Changing SelectedItem property of a ListView programatically

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a 2 `ListView`s with same items in both of them. What I want to do is that when a selection is made in one `ListView`, the same selection should be reflected in the other `ListView` also. The two `ListViews` are bound to two different ViewModels but both the ViewModels implement the same interface.
I've overridden the `Equals` methods in both ViewModels.

The two `ListView`s are on different XAML pages. The first `ListView` say `LV1` is in Page1.xaml and `LV2` is in Page2.xaml. What I want is that when I am changing the selection in `LV2` the selection in `LV1` should also change( one way only ). I've set `x:FieldModifier="public"` on `LV1` and exposing through a static property of Page1 like this:

```
public sealed partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public static Page1 page1 { get; private set; }
}
```

And on Page2, I have this :

```
private async void LV2_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var selected = e.ClickedItem as ISomeCommonInterface; 
    //Comparision is successful --> Contains() always returns corect value; 
    if (Page1.page1.LV1.Items.ToList().Contains(selected))
    {
        Page1.page1.LV1.SelectedItem = null; // this works
        Page1.page1.LV1.SelectedItem = selected; // this doesn't work
    }           
}
```

I've found that inside the `if` condition, assignment to null changes the `SelectedItem` of `LV1` to null but the next line doesn't change it to `selected` ( it remains null ).

Comment: Not an expert on UWP, but shouldn't `SelectedItem` be a `ListViewItem`? Maybe getting the index of the item you want to select from `LV1.Items` and then setting the `SelectedIndex` property is the way to go.

Comment: The index can be different, the two `ListView`s are bound to two different collections.

Comment: I got a feeling there's something wrong with your `Equals` impl and the `selected` reference doesn't exist in your `LV1.Items`.

Comment: I am sure my `Equals` always returns the right value.

Comment: You should be able to debug it. During debugging, just right click and make an object ID, and see if both IDs are the same.

Answer (score 0):

add after assignment:

```
Page1.page1.LV1.Select();
```

Comment: it's UWP, not WPF

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
private void LV1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selected = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem as string;
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < LV2.Items.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (LV2.Items[i] as string == selected){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // The if becomes obsolete here, it could be replaced by 
    // if(index >= 0) 
    if (LV2.Items.ToList().Contains(selected))
    {
        LV2.SelectedIndex = index;
    }
}
```

There is probably an easier way of getting the index of `LV1`'s `SelectedItem` in `LV2`, but it should be enough to get you on the right track.

You can check out the [minimal testing app](https://gist.github.com/Rastamas/99dfd482fd49e50c53f58be18ca0f2d6) I created that shows that `SelectedItem` works too.

Comment: yes, lastly I took this track and ordered the two lists identically and directly used the `SelectedIndex` property. But I am still not sure why original method doesn't work.

Comment: @ravikumar I just tried adding the same items to the lists, and it works with `SelectedItem`.

Comment: @ravikumar Maybe you are initializing the two `Items` collections with two copies of the same list?

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1 - `SelectionMode="Multiple"` - both ListViews in sync

You should subscribe the `SelectionChanged` event on both ListViews - item may not get selected only by click - and there (when selection is changed) you should sync the selection.

```
private void SyncSelection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listViewToAdd = ReferenceEquals(sender, firstListView) ? secondListView : firstListView;

    foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
    {
        if (!listViewToAdd.SelectedItems.Contains(item))
        {
            listViewToAdd.SelectedItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        listViewToAdd.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

### Method 2 - `SelectionMode="Multiple"` - update one after selecting in the other

You should subscribe the `SelectionChanged` event only on the ListView where items could be selected.

```
private void SyncSelection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
    {
        secondListView.SelectedItems.Add(item);
    }

    foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        secondListView.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

### Method 3 - `SelectionMode="Single"`

Subscribe the `SelectionChanged` event on both if you want to make them be in sync or only on the selectable one if you only want to update the second based on the first.

```
private void SyncSelection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView senderListView = (ListView)sender;
    ListView listViewToAdd = ReferenceEquals(sender, firstListView) ? secondListView : firstListView;
    listViewToAdd.SelectedItem = senderListView.SelectedItem;
}
```

You may need to replace `var` with your interface to make it work.